# Hour calculation

Tags: column, date-time

I have list with two date fields. It is also containing time information. It is based on leave request so I need to calculate hour basis for half a day leave.

If user enters `8/1/2016 08:00 AM` as start date and `8/1/2016 12:30 PM` as end date then I need to show `0.5` days.

If user enters `8/1/2016 08:00 AM` as start date and `9/1/2016 12:30 PM` as end date then I need to show `1.5` days.

Comment: Base will be =DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d") and you may have to play on the display to shoy the hour differences.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified calculation that I have used before and believe it will benefit you as well.

```
=DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date]-(MOD([Start Date],1)>MOD([End Date],1)),"d")&" days, "&TEXT(MOD([End Date]-[Start Date],1),"hh "" hrs, "" mm "" mins""")
```

For example: If a user enters 8/1/2016 8:00 AM as start date and 8/10/2016 12:30 PM as end date, your Output would look like this: 9 days, 4 hrs, 30 mins

Though you can format to better fit your situation.